# Bound TextBox does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, observablecollection

I have a ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection of objects (with several properties).  The Combo Box accurately displays the desired property of all objects and I can select any item from the Combo as expected.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1" Width="120" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}" DisplayMemberPath="Issue" SelectedValuePath="Issue" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Issues}" IsEditable="False" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" LostFocus="comboBox1_LostFocus" KeyUp="comboBox1_KeyUp" Loaded="comboBox1_Loaded" DropDownClosed="comboBox1_DropDownClosed" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

I have a series of text boxes which are supposed to display other properties of the selected object.  This works fine too.

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox5" Width="59" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Issues/LastSale, StringFormat={}{0:N4}}" />
<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox9" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=Issues/LastUpdate, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" />
```

BUT... The properties of ObservableCollection are updated in the Code-Behind on a regular basis and I make a change to the OC by either adding or removing a dummy object in it every time the properties are updated.  (I found this simpler than other solutions).

BUT...the data in the TextBoxes DO NOT change! :-(  If I select a different object from the ComboBox I get updated info, but it does not change when the OC is changed.

The OC is composed of a bunch of these Objects:

```
public class IssuesItems
{
  public String Issue { get; set; }
  public Double LastSale { get; set; }
  public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
  ...
 }
```

The OC is defined as:

```
public ObservableCollection<IssuesItems> Issues { get; set; }
```

and instantiated:

```
this.Issues = new ObservableCollection<IssuesItems>();
```

What am I doing wrong?  Everything I read says that when the LastSale and LastUpdate properties are changed in the OC (and I do something to force an update of the OC) the data in the text boxes ought to change.

Comment: Are you raising `propertychanged` event every time the `ObservableCollection` is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which *allows GUI to refresh when any item is added or deleted from collection* (you need not to worry about doing it manually).

But like i mentioned this is restricted to only addition/deletion of items from collection but  **if you want GUI to refresh when any underlying property gets changed, your underlying source class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`** to give notification to GUI that property has changed so refresh yourself.

`IssuesItems` should implement INPC interface in your case.

Refer to this - [How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
  public class IssuesItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string issue;
      public string Issue
      {
          get { return issue; }
          set
          {
              if(issue != value)
              {
                 issue= value;
                 // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
                 OnPropertyChanged("Issue");
              }
          }
      }

      // Declare the event 
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
```

Implement other properties just like `Issue` as mentioned above.

Comment: I do an add() or RemoveAt() every time after I change a batch of properties.  I would think that this would trigger the built-in OC Event as you say above.  BUT!!  I think I understand!  My add/remove causes the LIST of IssueItems (the collection) to be updated BUT NOT the value of items that have pre-existed.  Is that right?  If I had replaced old items with new items containing the new data, then my add/remove thing would work.